# while downloading MiKTeX packages in windows 7 I got the following error

Tags: miktex, installing

[image: error I get every time while trying to download MiKTeX]

I am trying to download MiKTeX in my laptop(windows 7 64 bit) but whenever i download, after some time the following screen appears and the downloading discards. I have no idea how to fix it, so, I would be grateful for any suggestions regarding it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What are you downloading exactly – the entire distribution, or individual packages?

Comment: It appears that there has been an update  yesterday with files date 7 and 8/5, but the data base files  `miktex-zzdb-i-2.9.tar.lzma` date from  7/5, whereas most package files are dated from 8/5, whence the error message. I suppose they will be updated in the next few days.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was actually downloading the entire distribution.

Comment: You may try again. There has been an update this week-end with correct database  files.